# Parsing single column of XML in data.frame

Tags: r, xml, dplyr

I have been given data as a data.frame but one column contains a cells each containing several xml elements.

Something like this ...

```
label_col = c("A", "B")

number_col = c(123, 456)

XML_col = c("<CD><TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE><ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST></CD><CD><TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE><ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST></CD>", 
             "<CD><TITLE>ABC</TITLE><ARTIST>XYZ</ARTIST></CD><CD><TITLE>EFG</TITLE><ARTIST>UVW</ARTIST></CD></CATALOG>")

Sample_df = data.frame(label_col, number_col, XML_col)
```

Now I can see that XML in each cell isn't contained by a single pair of tags so I add them

```
library(dplyr)

Sample_df %>%
mutate(XML_col = paste0("<Data>",XML_col,"</Data>"))
```

Now because each XML element contains multiple (2) items I would expect my dataframe to go from 2 x 3 to 4 x 4 (columns being... label_col, number_col, TITLE, ARTIST).

I'm stuck!  I've tried using unnest and unnest_longer but I don't really understand what to do.

Most examples about xml parsing seem to start with an XML file not a mix as above.

Can someone give me a steer? (Don't say Moo!)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the unmatched `</CATALOG>` tag is just a typo and that your actual input is validated, well-formed XML.

The general steps are

1. parse the character string into the R class `xml_document`
2. extract the target nodes as a list column
3. unnest the list column

Below demonstrates how to do it for the `TITLE` nodes, but should be easily replicated for the other nodes as well.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(xml2)
library(tidyr)

label_col <- c("A", "B")

number_col <- c(123, 456)

# dropped unmatched <CATALOG> tag
XML_col <- c("<CD><TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE><ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST></CD><CD><TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE><ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST></CD>", 
             "<CD><TITLE>ABC</TITLE><ARTIST>XYZ</ARTIST></CD><CD><TITLE>EFG</TITLE><ARTIST>UVW</ARTIST></CD>")

data.frame(label_col, number_col, XML_col) %>%
  mutate(
    XML_col = paste0("<Data>",XML_col,"</Data>"),
    XML_col = map(XML_col, read_xml),
    XML_titles = map(XML_col, ~xml_find_all(.x, ".//TITLE") %>% xml_text())
  ) %>% 
  unnest(XML_titles)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   label_col number_col XML_col    XML_titles      
#>   <chr>          <dbl> <list>     <chr>           
#> 1 A                123 <xml_dcmn> Empire Burlesque
#> 2 A                123 <xml_dcmn> Hide your heart 
#> 3 B                456 <xml_dcmn> ABC             
#> 4 B                456 <xml_dcmn> EFG
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @Markus It took me a little while to get back to the problem but your solution works perfectly.  Many Thanks!